# Is there way to benchmark your computer with java code?

Tags: java, maven, jvm, benchmarking

I'm java developer and my goal is to understand which computer is best suited for some statistical evaluation. I have 3 different desktops with different os(Windows 7, MacOS, Ubuntu). 
JVM based program seems best suited for this benchmark.
Is there some maven besed package which I can put to dependency and run on all these desktops to get HDD/CPU/Memory benchmark?

> The question is about java libraries which provides CPU/IO/memory benchmarks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in any meaningful way, AFAIK.  The purpose you have proposed "some statistical evaluation" is too broad for meaningful benchmarking.

In fact, the only meaningful approach would be to:

1. Select the statistical application that you are going to use.
2. Select a bunch of **representative** problems; i.e. problems that are typically of what you are going to be doing ... in both quality and "size".
3. Code the solutions using your selected application.
4. Run the solutions, and measure the times taken.
5. Tune the solutions / application and repeat the previous step until you are satisfied that you are getting the best performance out of the application.
6. Run the application on the candidate machines.
7. Compare the times, across all of your problems on all machines.

---

I would posit that unless you are trying to run really large analyses on an underpowered machine, it is not going to make much difference which OS you use.  The critical issues are likely to be using a fast enough machine with enough memory (if the analysis requires lots of memory), picking the right application, coding the solutions correctly, and tuning the application.  The choice of OS probably won't matter ... unless you push the memory envelope too hard.

---

> I will disagree. If what you are saying is correct there were no such think as SUperPI, 3DMark etc. Only problem with that stuff it is OS specific so I can compare 2 windows laptops only. Performance can be easly measured with elemntal operations such as write/read disk/memmory. Arithmetical operations. Thats is actaully universe of possible computer operations.

Well fine.

If you think you can find a meaningful benchmark that compares application-level performance across different OSes ... go find one.

And if you think such a benchmark is going to give you numbers that are applicable to running Java statistical analysis tools, feel free to use it.  (Hint: the OS-specific benchmarks like SUperPI, 3DMark, etc are not great predictors of performance running applications.)

And if you think that Java application performance is only about how fast disk read/write, memory read/write and basic arithmetic instructions ... feel free to continue believing that.

Unfortunately, reality is very different.

---

But my guess is that doesn't make a lot of difference what OS you choose, provided that the hardware is up to it.

Comment: I will disagree. If what you are saying is correct there were no such think as SUperPI, 3DMark etc. Only problem with that stuff it is OS specific so I can compare 2 windows laptops only.

Performance can be easly measured with elemntal operations such as write/read disk/memmory. Arithmetical operations. Thats is actaully universe of possible computer operations.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Anyway standard benchmark(such as superPI) are useful, and platform independent even more useful. So question about java pacakges which provides CPU/IO/memmory benchmarks...

Comment: The answer is that I am not aware of any.